# Is the Plugin Registration Tool not recognizing SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

<sub>Notice: this exact question can be found [on the dynamics community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/191538) which as usual isn't exactly responsive...</sub>

I can't figure out what's wrong with this environment...

CRM and ADFS are on the same server, different ports:

By browser, navigating to `https://myorg.mydomain:444` redirects to `https://sts1.mydomain:442` adfs login screen shows up, I input credentials, then I'm redirected back to CRM, everything works perfectly no matter which organization I navigate to. The SSL certificate is a wildcard one, covering `*.mydomain` (again, no issues whatsoever). Outlook client also works without a hitch.

My issue is, the registration tool (I'm using the one from the 2016 SDK, but this also happens with the 2013 SDK's one ) doesn't seem to be able to connect.

The exception message showing up in the log is (I'm translating from my native language to english, messages might not be 100% accurate)

```
[Top] Unable to establish a trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'sts1.mydomain'

[Inner level 1] Underlying connection closed: <same as above>

[Inner level 2] The remote certificate wasn't deemed valid from the validation procedure
```

Nothing in particular stands out in the Event Viewer... What's wrong ?

Just before writing this, I also tried the 2011 Registration Tool and it spits out a different error: it attempts to login to ADFS through HTTP instead of HTTPS (it complains about not finding `http://sts1.mydomain:442` which doesn't exist).

I also tried importing the aforementioned SSL cert into my trusted root cert authorities, it doesn't seem to matter (everything stays the same).

Update: I forgot to show the connection settings:

```
(o) On-Premises ( ) Office 365
Server: myorg.mydomain
PORT:   444   [X] Use SSL
Authentication Source: IFD
Username: DOMAIN\USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
Domain:   <BLANK>
[X] Display list
```

Comment: Are you only able to connect via IFD, no regular Windows Auth for LAN users?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't started fiddling with plugins in 2016 so I'm not sure how that works and which endpoint it's using but I'd try the 2011 plugin registration tool too. It's what I've been using up until now and I think it is a better one than the 2013 and later since you can have multiple servers setup in it.

Regards

Comment: Ok, I've tried the 2016 tool and it has a couple of settings, what have you entered for data to connect to you IFD implementation?

Comment: Appending the settings to the question (I forgot those)

Comment: Try to add the domain to the domain field (I used domain\username and then also added the domain in the domain field).

Comment: Another thought, have you enabled the trace in CRM, if not, do so to have a look what that says. 
The Error message above, where did you get that? Have you had a look at what the adfs/sts server error log says?

Comment: CRM and ADFS are on the same server, nothing in the events. Nothing is traced either, even if I set it to `"*:Verbose"`

Comment: That's strange, you should really get some sort of error either on the CRM server or the ADFS (or both). I've installed a few CRMs with IFD on one machine, not any 2016 though. Without any server errors it's sort of tricky finding the cause.